# Kendo : How to render a kendo.View or a kendo.Layout from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, single-page-application

I would like to know if it is possible to load the content of a **kendo.View(...)** or **kendo.layout(...)** from a separate *html* file?

This is the example from Kendo [Hello World Single Page Application](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/spa/overview) :

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script id="index" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    Hello <span data-bind="text: foo"></span>
</script>

<script>
    var index = new kendo.View(
        "index", // the id of the script element that contains the view markup
        { model: kendo.observable({ foo: "World!" }) }
    );

    var router = new kendo.Router();

    router.route("/", function() {
        index.render("#app");
    });

    $(function() {
        router.start();
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to do somethink like this :

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script>
    var index = new kendo.View(
        "hello.html", // the path of the script element that contains the view markup
        { model: kendo.observable({ foo: "World!" }) }
    );

    var router = new kendo.Router();

    router.route("/", function() {
        index.render("#app");
    });

    $(function() {
        router.start();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a way to do it. Here is documentation on how to do it: [Kendo Remote Templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/load-templates-external-files)

Here is the gist of it:

1. You need to make a template loader that basically reads html/string from a file. Kendo does not supply one in the box but this is the one that they use in their example.([templateLoader.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3087987)). Include it on the your html page.
2. Add your templates in a separate html file. You can store multiple templates in the same file. However you should only be putting templates there ideally. Let's say this is in file `mytemplate.html`

   ```html
   <script id="index" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       Hello <span data-bind="text: foo"></span>
   </script>
   ```
3. On your main html page, add a `<script>` block that calls your template loader with that template file. This will/should inject the templates onto your main page and then you should be able to use it as if it was a local template.

   ```html
   <script>
       templateLoader.loadExtTemplate("mytemplate.html");
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done this way atm. I'm not even sure if it should be doable.

Perhaps fetch the template beforehand using `$.get()` or `.load()`?

edit: using `.load()` you'd have to dynamically create script template and using `$.get()` append the script template somewhere in the document.

Comment: The view constructor also accepts markup as a string (this is more like a side-effect from jQuery).

Comment: Could you give me an example. I'm noob in Javascript. I tried soltuions without success.

Comment: Also See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote